# How can one pad zeroes in-between non-consecutive float elements of a sorted list that contains duplicates?

Tags: list, python-3.x, numpy, enumerate, pad

I have a list of float values that represent the time of an observation. (Each float value can actually be represented as an integer, but I am hoping to generalize for possible future circumstances).

```
list_hrs = [4,6,8,8,10] # actual list is thousands of floats
```

I am trying to pad the values that don't match their indices with zero while counting only a single occurrence of duplicate entries. Per the example list, I would want

```
list_hrs = [0,0,0,0,4,0,6,0,8,8,0,10]
```

The first four entries are `0` because there are inclusively four numbers from `0` to `3`. The `0` between `4` and `6` is wanted there because `5` is missing; similarly for the `0` between `6` and `8`. The `0` between `8` and `10` is wanted there because the value `9` is missing. Also, the duplicate `8`'s are left untouched, as they will be dealt with later in my code; only a single occurrence of the duplicate `8`'s should be counted before padding `0`'s.

My first attempt was to try this:

```
for index in range(len(list_hrs)):
    if list_hrs != index:
        list_hrs.insert(index, 0)

>> [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4, 6, 8, 8, 10]
```

I then read different SO posts and came away with the impression that it's best to first make a list of `0`'s, for which the length should be equal to the number of data points considered. Then, the non-zero entries can replace the `0` entries. So, I tried the following:

```
def make_zeros(hrs=list_hrs): # make list of 0's
    num_zer = int(max(hrs))
    list_zer = [0 for index in range(num_zer+1)]
    return list_zer
```

But I am unsure of how to implement the condition to achieve the desired result after this point. I am thinking there is a way to use `enumerate` to check if the index matches the value at that index, but am unsure how to proceed due to duplicate entries (such as the `8`'s in the example above).

Is this method a good direction to keep going in, or is there a more efficient / simpler way to achieve the desired result? Any help or advice would be appreciated.

Comment: Why are they floats, are you expecting decimal numbers in there? Like could there be say `4.2`? If so, how should the output look like?

Comment: Also, would the input be always sorted?

Comment: Each float can actually be interpreted as an integer. The example list should actually be `[4.0,6.0,8.0,8.0,10.0]`. I was just hoping to generalize the code. But if there is a solution for the case of integers, it will work fine for this case.

Comment: Yes, the list is always sorted. I originally had separate lists for years, months, days, etc. I converted all the time markers into hours, and reset the count such that the first occurrence is at 0 hours. The observations are logged chronologically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one vectorized approach -

```
def make_zeros_vectorized(A, dtype=float):
    a = np.asarray(A).astype(int)
    idx = a + np.r_[0, (a[1:] == a[:-1]).cumsum()]
    out = np.zeros(idx[-1]+1,dtype=dtype)
    out[idx] = A
    return out
```

Sample runs -

```
In [95]: A
Out[95]: [4.0, 6.0, 8.0, 8.0, 10.0, 10.0, 10.0, 14.0, 16.0]

In [96]: make_zeros_vectorized(A)
Out[96]: 
array([  0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   4.,   0.,   6.,   0.,   8.,   8.,   0.,
        10.,  10.,  10.,   0.,   0.,   0.,  14.,   0.,  16.])

In [100]: A
Out[100]: [4.0, 4.0, 4.0, 4.0, 6.0, 8.0, 8.0, 10.0, 10.0, 10.0, 14.0, 16.0]

In [101]: make_zeros_vectorized(A)
Out[101]: 
array([  0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   4.,   4.,   4.,   4.,   0.,   6.,   0.,
         8.,   8.,   0.,  10.,  10.,  10.,   0.,   0.,   0.,  14.,   0.,
        16.])
```

**Steps involved**

Input list

```
In [71]: A = [4.0,6.0,8.0,8.0,10.0,10.0,10.0,14.0,16.0]
```

Convert to array

```
In [72]: a = np.asarray(A).astype(int)

In [73]: a
Out[73]: array([ 4,  6,  8,  8, 10, 10, 10, 14, 16])
```

Create a mask of duplicates. The is central to this approach, as we plan to use cumulative summation later on. With the duplicates being represented as True, when cumulatively summed would result in incremental values, to be used as incremental indices for placing the input array values into the output array

```
In [74]: a[1:] == a[:-1]
Out[74]: array([False, False,  True, False,  True,  True, False, False], dtype=bool)

In [75]: (a[1:] == a[:-1]).cumsum()
Out[75]: array([0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 3])
```

Append a zero at the start, as the earlier "a[1:] == a[:-1]" would have resulted in one-element less array

```
In [76]: np.r_[0, (a[1:] == a[:-1]).cumsum()]
Out[76]: array([0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 3])
```

Finally, add to the input array so that the duplicates are shifted/added one-up and thus giving us the indices at which output array are to be assigned

```
In [77]: a + np.r_[0, (a[1:] == a[:-1]).cumsum()]
Out[77]: array([ 4,  6,  8,  9, 11, 12, 13, 17, 19])
```

Later steps are basically creating an output array and assigning values from `a` into it using indices obtained earlier.

---

If you need the mask of zeros or those indices, here's a modified version -

```
def get_zeros_mask(A):
    a = np.asarray(A).astype(int)
    idx = a + np.r_[0, (a[1:] == a[:-1]).cumsum()]
    mask = np.ones(idx[-1]+1,dtype=bool)
    mask[idx] = 0
    return mask
```

Sample run -

```
In [93]: A
Out[93]: [4.0, 6.0, 8.0, 8.0, 10.0, 10.0, 10.0, 14.0, 16.0]

In [94]: make_zeros_vectorized(A)
Out[94]: 
array([  0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   4.,   0.,   6.,   0.,   8.,   8.,   0.,
        10.,  10.,  10.,   0.,   0.,   0.,  14.,   0.,  16.])

In [95]: get_zeros_mask(A)
Out[95]: 
array([ True,  True,  True,  True, False,  True, False,  True, False,
       False,  True, False, False, False,  True,  True,  True, False,
        True, False], dtype=bool)

In [96]: np.flatnonzero(get_zeros_mask(A))
Out[96]: array([ 0,  1,  2,  3,  5,  7, 10, 14, 15, 16, 18])
```

Comment: The code works perfectly! If understand what you did, `np.r_` concatenates entries into a single list. I get that `cumsum` is a cumulative sum but what is that line of code actually doing?

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. While the other code is more flexible in terms of handling floats, this code is much much faster, which is useful for thousands of data points.

Comment: It would actually serve my purposes better to find the indices for which the zeroes should be padded. That way, I can pad zeroes for the observation times and observed values at those times (since an hour for which no observation occurred corresponds to an observed value of zero). I have been unable to adapt this code for this purpose. You were generous to give me a full working code for my original question; can you please help help me figure out a way to do this? Am I correct in trying to change `out[idx] = A` into something like `out[ not idx ] = A`? (I don't know the correct syntax).

Comment: Thanks for the helpful reply.

Comment: Just in case someone else finds it helpful, I found it to be more efficient and a bit simpler to avoid the mask approach and define a second function to `make_zeros_vectorized_2(A,B)` and replaced the line `out[idx] = A` with `out[idx] = B`. (That said, I'm grateful to be exposed to new topics like masking).

Answer (score 1):

Just another example:

```
list_hrs = [4,6,8,8,10]
lh = iter(list_hrs)
fit = range(int(max(list_hrs))+1)

result = [0 if i not in list_hrs else next(lh) for i in fit for _ in range(list_hrs.count(i)) or [1]]
```

Comment: I have never used `iter` before, but this makes sense to me. Thanks for the alternative approach.

Comment: This code is also more versatile as it can handle floats too.